# How to integrate Wso2 IS xacml with java MVC application

Tags: authorization, xacml, xacml3, abac, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to implement Wso2 identity server's XACML based access control with the JAVA MVC application.

**Use Case** : User logs in and view only selected pages/menus(and also the action on these page ex.view,post,delete etc.) defined in the XACML policy.

What I have checked in WSO2 IS XACML will return Permit/Deny/NotApplicable for particular resource.

So just want to know is this use case's solution is possible with the Wso2 IS XACML and how.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally possible. There are two ways you can achieve this.

1. **Using WSO2 Identity Server as the entitlement engine**

With this option. You can create and manage policies using WSO2 Identity Server provided policy editor. You can manage the lifecycle of policies (publish/unpublish) etc.

Then you can consume the SOAP Entitlement Service provided by Identity Server from your application. With IS 5.3.0 we provide a REST service for XACML as well.

Read more about these in [[1]](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2016/02/tutorial-how-to-enable-role-based-access-control-for-wso2-api-manager-using-xacml/), [[2]](http://manzzup.blogspot.com/2016/08/gsoc-2016-rest-implementation-for-wso2.html)

2. **Using WSO2 Balana entitlement Engine.**

[Balana](https://github.com/wso2/balana/) is WSO2's open source implementation of XACML. WSO2 Identity Server internally uses this library/engine for Entitlement. You can use this library directly in you application to achieve you use case. In fact, part of the use case is available as a [sample](https://github.com/wso2/balana/tree/master/modules/balana-samples/web-page-image-filtering) in Balana. This sample explain how Balana could be used to filter resources in a web page based on user(or his role). Read more about the sample [here](https://xacmlinfo.com/2012/08/16/resource-filtering-with-xacml/).

Comment: Thank you very much Farasath,  you are great.This is exactly what I was looking .

Comment: glad to be of help :)